# is it possible to continue a file upload after a browser has been quit?

Tags: http, file-upload

If a user starts uploading a file (in a web app), and they close their browser before the upload completes, what happens?

My guess would be that the upload gets abandoned, and the server has some garbage cleaning mechanism that kicks in eventually, but I'm not sure. Any difference between servers or server languages? Any difference between quitting the browser and just closing a window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a streaming so your guess is right in my opinion. No difference in closing a window because they're threads, aren't they?